# Write Python DataFrame as CSV into Azure Blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have got two questions on reading and writing Python objects from/to Azure blob storage.

1. Can someone tell me how to write Python dataframe as csv file directly into Azure Blob without storing it locally?

   I tried using the functions `create_blob_from_text` and `create_blob_from_stream` but none of them works.

   Converting dataframe to string and using `create_blob_from_text` function
   writes the file into the blob but as a plain string but not as csv.

   ```
   df_b = df.to_string()
   block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('test', 'OutFilePy.csv', df_b)
   ```
2. How to directly read a json file in Azure blob storage directly into Python?

Comment: See this to send the data as csv to blob : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923055/how-can-i-upload-a-dataframe-as-csv-to-azure-by-python/67225237#67225237

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> 1. Can someone tell me how to write Python dataframe as csv file
>    directly into Azure Blob without storing it locally?

You could use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

***Sample code:***

```
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService
)
import pandas as pd
import io

output = io.StringIO()
head = ["col1" , "col2" , "col3"]
l = [[1 , 2 , 3],[4,5,6] , [8 , 7 , 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame (l , columns = head)
print(df)
output = df.to_csv (index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")
print(output)

accountName = "***"
accountKey = "***"
containerName = "test1"
blobName = "test3.json"

blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)

blobService.create_blob_from_text('test1', 'OutFilePy.csv', output)
```

***Output result:***

[image]

> 2.How to directly read a json file in Azure blob storage directly into Python?

***Sample code:***

```
from azure.storage.blob import (
    BlockBlobService
)

accountName = "***"
accountKey = "***"
containerName = "test1"
blobName = "test3.json"

blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)

result = blobService.get_blob_to_text(containerName,blobName)

print(result.content)
```

***Output result:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: When I store the df.to_csv in a variable, it stores it in a local directory and the variable is of None type. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you would like to save the output to a subfolder then make this change:
blobService.create_blob_from_text('test1', 'folder1/folder2/OutFilePy.csv', output)

Answer (score 10):

The approved answer did not work for me, as it depends on the azure-storage (deprecated/legacy as of 2021) package. I changed it as follows:

```
from azure.storage.blob import *
import dotenv
import io
import pandas as pd

dotenv.load_dotenv()
blob_block = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=os.environ["CONNECTION_STRING"],
    container_name=os.environ["CONTAINER_NAME"]
    )
output = io.StringIO()
partial = df.DataFrame()
output = partial.to_csv(encoding='utf-8')
blob_block.upload_blob(name, output, overwrite=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: More info here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#create-a-container

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of writing a Python DataFrame into Azure Blob Storage without storing it locally. It doesn't require String.IO and uses the ContainerClient instead of BlockBlobService.

```py
import pandas as pd

def write_csv(env, df_path, df):
    container_client = ContainerClient(
        env['container_url'],
        container_name=env['container_name'],
        credential=env['container_cred']
    )

    output = df.to_csv (index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")
    print(output)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(df_path)
    blob_client.upload_blob(output, overwrite=True)

    return 'success'
```

Answer (score 1):

There was update in **BlobServiceClient**. **create_blob_from_text** method is no longer supported. Now you can use **get_blob_client** to get or create the blob file. [Blob need not exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobserviceclient-get-blob-client):

```
output = dataframe.to_csv(index_label="idx", encoding="utf-8")

blob_service = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
   f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={ACCOUNT_NAME};AccountKey= 
{ACCOUNT_KEY};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
)

container_client = blob_service.get_container_client(DEST_CONTAINER)
blob_client = blob_service.get_blob_client(container=DEST_CONTAINER, 
blob="kcScenarioTest/"+str(current_time.microsecond)+".csv") 

blob_client.upload_blob(output,overwrite=True,content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type="text/csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need a BytesIO file to upload to the blob, using the upload_blob method from azure.storage.blob module.  You will also need to create a cotainer_client from the same module

```
blob_report_name = 'OutFilePy.csv'
stream_file = BytesIO()
df_b.to_csv(stream_file)  
file_to_blob = stream_file.getvalue()
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_report_name)
blob_client.upload_blob(data=file_to_blob, overwrite=True)
```