# pandas and azure: DataFrame to_csv blob

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to store a python pandas DataFrame to Azure, but the solution by [Jay Gong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017842/5316326) (Python 2.7) gives me errors:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
service = BlockBlobService(
    account_name=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    account_key=STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY
)

with io.StringIO() as stream:
    df.to_csv(stream, encoding="utf-8")
    service.create_blob_from_text('containert', 'example.txt', stream)
```

Returns:

> AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'encode'

- python 3.7
- pandas 0.23.4
- azure-blob-storage 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
with io.StringIO() as streamio:
    df.to_csv(streamio, encoding = "utf-8", index=False)
    streamio.seek(0)
    service.create_blob_from_text('containert', 'example.txt', "".join(streamio.readlines()))
```