# Using azure.storage.blob to write Python DataFrame as CSV into Azure Blob

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I tried the example in the following link: [Write Python DataFrame as CSV into Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014827/write-python-dataframe-as-csv-into-azure-blob) But BlockBlobService is no longer available in azure.storage.blob, so I tried using BlockBlobClient and I can create, delete containers using the following code. However I can't find a way to create a blob in the container and write the records from a data frame into it as mentioned in the above link. Please help I want to create a blob and write the records from the dataframe into it.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blobService = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("**")
#blobService = BlobServiceClient(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)
try:
   new_container = blobService.create_container("containerfromblobservice")
   properties = new_container.get_container_properties()
except ResourceExistsError:
   print("Container already exists.")
```

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
# create data
head = ["col1" , "col2" , "col3"]
value = [[1 , 2 , 3],[4,5,6] , [8 , 7 , 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame (value, columns = head)
output = df.to_csv (index=False, encoding = "utf-8")
print(output)

connection_string=''
# Instantiate a new BlobServiceClient using a connection string
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
# Instantiate a new ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('mycsv')
try:
   # Create new Container in the service
   container_client.create_container()
   properties = container_client.get_container_properties()
except ResourceExistsError:
   print("Container already exists.")

# Instantiate a new BlobClient
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("output.csv")
# upload data
blob_client.upload_blob(output, blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-python?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#blob-samples)